# Weak star topology on a finite dimensional space coincides with the standart topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to show that if $X$ is a finite dimensional normed space, then $*$-weak topology on $X^*$ coincides with the standard topology.

First of all, if $X$ is finite dimensional then $\mbox{dim}X = \mbox{dim}X^*$ and $X^*$ is also finite dimensional. Denote by $\tau^*$ the weak star topology on $X^*$ and by $\tau$ its standard topology. To show that they coincide means to show that $\tau = \tau^*$.

Why $\tau^* \subseteq \tau$? It is obvious directly from the definition of $*$-weak topology that every $U \in \tau^*$ is an open subset in ordinary meaning because we want every $ev_x\colon X^*\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous map and that inclusion takes place even in infinite dimensional case.

But why $\tau \subseteq \tau^*$ and how should I use that $X^*$ is finite dimensional? Can someone show me a proof of this inclusion?

Comment: Do you know that there is only one locally convex topology on a finite dimensional space? In order to show $\tau \subset \tau^*$, you can use a basis and the corresponding coefficient functionals (i.e., the functionals which map a point to its coefficients w.r.t. a fixed basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $X = \mathbb K^n$. It suffices to show that each element of a base of $\tau$ is also in $\tau^\ast$. As a base we can use sets of the form $U = \prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i)$ with $a_i<b_i$ for each $i$. Let $\pi_i\in X^\ast$ be the $i$-th canonical projection. Then $U = \bigcap_{i=1}^n {\pi_i}^{-1}(a_i,b_i)$, hence $U\in \tau^\ast$.